# Insert API endpoint ignores Slug header

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The filename of the inserted video is set with the "Slug" HTTP header. This worked correctly when I last used the API back at the start of 2020. Now it doesn't seem to be working, and all my videos have empty video filenames. Has this intentionally been removed from the API? There's no mention of the change in the API release notes...

Comment: This might be a bug, for issues about the functionality of the API, please consider research if your issue has been posted on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803) or post your issue there.

Comment: Done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168642902